# I want to change a property name at runtime in java

Tags: java, maven, properties

I am working on java maven project.
I have added a property as

```
mapred.input = value
```

Now i want to modify it as

```
mapred.input.tablename = value
```

So that i can use this property as follow :

```
mapred.input.table1 = value
mapred.input.table2 = value
```

Somebody please help me with this . how property should be added so that i can use this property for different table.

Thanks

Comment: System.setProperty ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the new property and clear the old property

```
System.setProperty("mapred.input.tablename", System.getProperty("mapred.input"));
System.clearProperty("mapred.input");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the property key/value pair as

```
mapred.input.{table}= {value}
```

Use MessageFormat (import it from java.text package ) to format the message by passing parameter values as follows,

```
String message = "mapred.input.{table}= {value}";
MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat(message);
String strMsg = mf.format(new Object[] {"table1","value1"});
```